# google map not centering on markers ONLY when in modal

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Take a look at this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CdRdd/2/. See how the map is offcenter of the markers? Now take a look at the same map when not in the modal http://jsfiddle.net/CdRdd/4/ it works. What's going on?

```
function initialize() {
  var addresses = $('.tracking-map-marker-details');

  window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas_trackingmap'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
      bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    $(addresses).each(function() {
        var address  = $(this).data('address'),
            letter   = $(this).data('letter'),
            status   = $(this).data('status');

      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + letter + ".png",
            shadow: 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map
            });

            bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
        }
      });
    });

  var listener = google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function () {
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    map.setZoom(5);

    $('#tracking_map_modal').modal('show').on('shown', function () {
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });
  });     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`google.maps.Map fitBounds` will only ensure that your map's viewport will contain the given bounds.

You want to make a call to [`google.maps.Map setCenter`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map), passing in your marker's `latLng`:

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    // var marker = ...;
    window.map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, I want the map to be centered based on the bounds. How to do that?

Comment: You're already doing that. "Bounds" consists of four points that make up your bounding box. Google Maps deal with them via a [`LatLngBounds` object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) that tracks the North East and South West corners of your bounding box.

Comment: Ok. Did you see the jsfiddle? The map is off center of the markers. If you can update the jsfiddle with working example then that would be lovely

Comment: I've given you the answer you need. You're already setting the viewport bounds. If you want to center around the marker, use the code in my answer. Otherwise, clarify your question.

Comment: Actually no this is not the answer. The map is already centered on the markers without this. The problem appears only when the map is in the modal

Answer (score 1):

Answer is to setCenter after modal is shown

```
$('#tracking_map_modal').modal('show').on('shown', function () {
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
      map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
 });
```